# Sqlite datetime convert to .Net datetime

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin

Xamarin SQLiteConnection cant' convert datetime value.
Here is my query :

```
var getDocumentsQuery = @"Select d.CreateDate From Docume Where d.IsSynced=0 ";
var documents = _db.Query<DocumentDTO> (getDocumentsQuery);
```

DocumentDTO class has property

```
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
```

where I execute query direct to sqlite database it returns such value:

> 2015-10-21 04:20:30

but from xamarin , in my documents every DocumentDTO object has default datetime value:

> documents[0].CreateDate   {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}  System.DateTime

So, SQLConnection unable to convert datetime value correct

Comment: which specific SQLite library are you using?  I've never had a problem with converting a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

What's the column type of CreateDate in the database table? If it's a text type then it might not be properly converted to a DateTime.

As per previous answer, what Sql Lite library is it? Some are an ORM library so they handle this for you, but worth checking

Comment: I'm using SQLite.Net-PCl v2.2 and  SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid v2.2